# How to identify lines ending with 5 in a file

Tags: linux, unix, grep, cygwin, gnu

I have a file `test.lst` whose contents are like below.
Using CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64.
I need to select only those lines which do not end with `5`.

```
12
23
45
56
45
23
09
12
99
100
0000
9999999
```

The output should be:

```
12
23
56
23
09
12
99
100
0000
9999999
```

with `grep -v '5$' test.txt`, I am getting below:

```
[2014-11-28 17:42.57]  /drives/d/Shantanu/MyScript
[463615.PC172645] ➤ grep -v '5$' test.txt
12
23
45
56
45
23
09
12
99
100
0000
9999999
[2014-11-28 17:43.21]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just grep out them:

```
grep -v '5$' file
```

This looks for lines ending with `5` (`$` refers to the end of line). Then `-v` inverts the match.

For your input it returns:

```
12
23
56
23
09
12
99
100
0000
9999999
```

Comment: [2014-11-28 17:42.57]  /drives/d/Shantanu/MyScript
[4567.PC1234] ➤ grep -v '5$' test.txt
12
23
45
56
45
23
09
12
99
100
0000
9999999

Comment: Please update your question indicating the output. In comments it is not possible to see it properly. Also, what is your `grep` version? do `grep --version`.

Comment: GNU grep 2.5.3
        
Copyright (C) 1988, 1992-2002, 2004, 2005  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: Your file is likely to contain some weird characters. Can you try `cat -vet file`?

Comment: i am currently using mobaxterm (GNU) on windows .. may be this doesnt support lots of things .. will try in Linux box when I have access and share the outcome .. I am sure 5$ will work in linux box .. dont know why GNU is not working with that

Comment: @Shantanu yes, it is weird. That's why I was asking if the file contains any strange characters that prevent `grep` working normally.

Comment: yes on my linux sed/grep every thing worked .. still dont know what is issue with this GNU .. really wierd

Answer (score 0):

You could use inverse grep search or inverse search using sed like below:

```
sed -n '/5$/!p' test.txt

or

grep -v "5$" test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a negated character class.

```
grep '[^5]$' file
```

`[^5]$` matches the last character at the last which wouldn't be a number `5`. By default grep would print all the lines which has a match.